# Передать данные по нажатию кнопки

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Возник интересный вопрос, как мне лучше всего передавать someValue в somefunction,
 при нажатии кнопки: оформить все это в форму или лучше использовать иной способ?

```
  <li key={someKeygen}>
    {someValue }
    <button onClick={this.somefunction.bind(this)}>Добавить</button>
  </li>
```

Comment: Используйте обработчики событий.

Comment: а так? `<button onClick={this.somefunction.bind(this, someValue)}>Добавить</button>`

Answer (score 0):

**Вариант 1.** Передавайте someValue в аттрибуте data:

```
<li key={someKeygen}>
    {someValue }
    <button 
        onClick={this.somefunction}
        data-some-value={someValue}
    >
        Добавить
    </button>
</li>
```

обработчик:

```
somefunction = (event) => {
    let someValue = event.target.datastore.someValue;
}
```

**Вариант 2.** Создайте отдельный компонент для элемента и передавайте ему someValue через props

```
class MyItem extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <button 
                onClick={this.onClick}
            >
                {this.props.children}
            </button>
        );
    }

    onClick = () => {
        this.props.onClick(this.props.value);
    }
}
```

список:

```
<li key={someKeygen}>
    <MyItem
        value={someValue}
        onClick={this.somefunction}
    >
        Добавить
    </MyItem>
</li>
```

обработчик:

```
somefunction = (value) => {
    let someValue = value;
}
```

**Вариант 3.** Указан в комментарии @Misha Saidov к вашему вопросу